# TabLayout cannot be resolved even with all dependencies

Tags: android, android-tablayout, android-design-library

I am able to use TabLayout in my design and it even shows up in the emulator:

```
     <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" Monitor"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="About US" />


    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

However, I am not able to create a TabLayout object in my activity:

```
TabLayout tabLayout = new TabLayout(this);
tabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener...
```

it complains: "cannot resolve symbol 'TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener'". I included all required dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
```

Comment: Use TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener pageChangeListener = new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout);

Answer (score 0):

In place of

> tabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener...

```
TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener pageChangeListener = new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout);
```

and set it to your viewpager.